# Why did Burndown widget on dashboard lose data when the Team's area path association changed?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm not a frequent stackoverflow user, so sorry if this is not an appropriate question. Microsoft's documentation pointed me here and I can't find an appropriate tag or place to ask in "super user"... 
We are using Azure DevOps for application lifecycle management. This question is specific to the Dashboards capability of the product and the Burndown widget that comes out of the box for dashboards. We had a Burndown chart that showed data for 3 teams that has been working for a year. We changed strategy on our usage of Area Paths and these 3 teams got associated to new area paths, and all their current and historical work items also got updated to the new area paths. After that data change, the Burndown charts are no longer working. 
Any ideas on how to fix? Or insight to how the widget works that may lead us to a better way to handle without breaking in future? Thanks!

Comment: There's also a DevOps site https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try reconfiguring the burndown widget and set the filter value to the new area path. On the top right corner of the burndown widget and click on the 3dots to open configuration page.
[image]

Then you can modify the Field criteria change the area path value to the new area path or other settings if necessary.

**Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops) to learn more about how to configure burndown widget**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have read all the documentation and the problem is it is not pulling any data at all. So adding a field filter doesn't help me. It still says "0"

Comment: @erinhelf did you try creating a new burndown widget and configure the settings according to previous burndown widget and the new area path the teams.

Comment: yes, we got same result of all history is lost, but as of the week we changed the areas, it is now collecting data. We are looking for a way to change the area paths w/o losing the history.

Comment: I suggest you report this issue to [Microsoft Dev Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following
Go to Project settings --> Under Boards click Team Configuration --> on the right hand side panel go to the tab Areas (3rd tab) --> add the area paths by clicking the "+Select Areas" button.

In the Dashboard, It will work after few mins.